# Query filtering a collection using spring specifications

Tags: spring-data

I have an entity A (ManyToMany, direct, lazy) which holds a reference to a collection of entities B.

I need to query the DB, searching for entities A based on the elements of class B it references. How can I do that with Spring specifications?

Comment: What are "Spring specifications"? What are you trying to do exactly? Which error do you run into?

Comment: These Specifications: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#specifications
I'm trying to query the DB for entities A filtering them against entities B, of which A hold a collection. Such as 'get the A entities which contain these B objects'.

Comment: That's way to little information to help. Please provide code you have, a test case that shows what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you can do it this way :

```
@Entity
public class A{

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(....)
private Set<B> bs;
// getters and Setters

}
```

Class B , let's suppose you want to query by comparing a b.property

```
@Entity
public class B{
@Column
private String property;
// getters and setters 
}
```

An Abstract Class to provide the Specifications :

```
public abstract class ASpecifications{
    public static Specification<A> findByProperty(final String prop) {
        return new Specification<A>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<A> root,
                    CriteriaQuery<?> arg1, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                return cb.equal(root.join(A_.bs).get(B_.property), prop);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now use it @ the service layer this way :

```
import static package.ASpecifications.*;
import static org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications.where;

@Transactional(...)
public List<A> findByJoinPropertyOFB(String prop){
Specifications<A> spec = where(findByProperty(prop));
retrun repository.findAll(spec);
}
```

Now make sure that your Repository extends `JpaSpecificationExecutor<A>`

If B Contains a reference To another Object `C` and you want to compare throw a value of C

the spec can be  extended this way :

```
cb.equal(root.join(A_.bs).get(B_c).get(c_.property), prop);
```

`B_` , `C_` And `A_` are MetaModels of  your entities. 
Hope this will help.